# Разбить один масив на два по ключу PHP

Tags: php

Как можно наиболее быстро разбить такой массив:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => bob
    [guest] => 3
    [team_res] => 47
    [doc_arr] => 33
    [dex_res] => 23
    [nks_res] => 54
    [line_arr] => 87
    [ind_res] => 72
    [info_arr] => 5
)
```

ну и т.д, строк много.

Как с него получить два новых массива такого вида:

```
Array
(
    [team_res] => 47
    [dex_res] => 23
    [nks_res] => 54
    [ind_res] => 72
)

Array
(
    [doc_arr] => 33
    [line_arr] => 87
    [info_arr] => 5
)
```

Comment: Например [этой функцией](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php). Полный список функций для работы с массивами можно найти [тут](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.array.php)

Comment: А как бы вы наиболее быстро сделали это вручную, если бы у вас была стопка бумажек, на которых было бы написано типа "doc_arr: 33"? Представьте такую ситуацию.